# How to fix 404-post on Nginx?

Tags: node.js, angular, nginx

I have deployed my website on the server nginx. Everything is working as expected but there is just a minor problem. On the contact page, depending on the language that is selected , I have a form .  I am getting post 404 error. POST https://example.com/en/contact 404 (Not Found).  This is only happening when I click on the submit button. My application is build in Angular and Node JS .

***I have change the original information and the original routes with dummy text

this is my node.js file

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

const port = 3000;

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "*******",
  port: 587,
  secure: false,
  auth: {
    user: process.env.EMAIL,
    pass: process.env.PASS
  }
});

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/:lang/:contact', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const {name,email,phone,message} = req.body;
    const {lang, contact} = req.params;

    await transporter.sendMail({
      from: `${email}`,
      to: 'email',
      subject: `Порака од веб страната`,
      html: `<div style="font-size: 20px;">
          <div><b></b> ${name}</div>
          <div><b></b> ${phone}</div>
          <div><b></b> ${email}</div>
          <div><b></b> ${message}</div>`
    });
    res.status(200).json({ message:  'Email sent successfully'});
  } catch(error) {
    console.error('Error sending email:', error);
    res.status(500).send('Error sending email')
  }
});


app.use(express.static('/var/www/path/to/dist/file', {
  setHeaders: (res, filePath) => {
      const ext = path.extname(filePath);
      const mimeTypes = {
          '.html': 'text/html',
          '.js': 'application/javascript',
          '.css': 'text/css',
      };
      const contentType = mimeTypes[ext];
      if (contentType) {
          res.setHeader('Content-Type', contentType);
      }
  }
}));

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on ${port}`);
});
```

this is my email.service.ts file  - where i am handling my http post

```
export class EmailService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private languageService: LanguageService) { }


  private getBaseUrl(): string {
    const lang = this.languageService.getCurrentLanguage();
    switch (lang) {
      case 'en':
        return 'https://test.com/en/contact';
      case 'de':
        return 'https://test.com/de/kontakt';
      default:
        return 'https://example.com/en/contact';
    }
  }

  sendMail(name: string, email: string, phone: string, message: string) {
    const baseUrl = this.getBaseUrl();
    const data = {
      name: name,
      email: email,
      phone: phone,
      message: message
    };
    return this.http.post(baseUrl, data);
  }
```

this is my conf file in nginx

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;   
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl-certificates/ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl-certificates/crt;
    server_name name.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl-certificates/ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl-certificates/crt;
    server_name example.com www1.example.com;
    root  /path/to/filex/;
    access_log  /path/to/acc/logs;
    error_log /path/to/err/logs;

    if ($scheme != "https") {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$uri permanent;
    }

    location = / {
        return 301 /en/home;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
        proxy_connect_timeout 900;
        proxy_send_timeout 900;
        proxy_read_timeout 900;
        proxy_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_buffers 4 256k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        auth_basic off;
        allow all;
    }

    index index.html;
}
```

this is my form.component.ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { EmailService } from 'src/app/services/email.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.scss', '/media_queries.scss']
})
export class FormComponent {
  message = false;
  isSubmitted = false;
  form = this.fb.group({
    name : ['', Validators.required],
    email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email, Validators.pattern(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,20})+$/)]],
    phone: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^\+?(?:[0-9] ?){0,13}[0-9]$/)]],   
    message: ['', Validators.required]
  })
  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder,private service:EmailService){}

  onSubmit(): void{
    this.isSubmitted = true;
    

    this.service.sendMail(
      this.form.get('name')?.value || '', 
      this.form.get('email')?.value || '', 
      this.form.get('phone')?.value || '', 
      this.form.get('message')?.value || ''
  ).subscribe({
         next: (response) => {
        // console.log('Email sent successfully');
        this.form.reset();
        this.isSubmitted = false;
        this.message = true;
      },
      error: (error) => {
        // console.error('Error sending email:', error);
        this.isSubmitted = false;
      }

      });
      
    }
    isInvalid(param:any) {
      return this.form.get(param)?.invalid &&
    (this.form.get(param)?.dirty || this.form.get(param)?.touched || this.isSubmitted);
  }
}
```

Everything in working well on local host the problem is on the server.
I really don't know where is the error.  Before this error I was receiving mixed content , but now that error is gone.